# Copy permissions of Windows folders

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions, access-control-list

For Windows 2008 R2, is there a way to copy the permissions when you copy-paste the folder? Or a way to easily document the permissions for all files/folders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way forward is:

```
ROBOCOPY <source> <dest> [copy options] /SEC
```

Used it many times.  If you're copying between servers (you don't state whether it's a local copy), any permissions defined using local groups will appear as an unknown SID on the target.  This holds true for any copy method.

Comment: Thanks, Simon. This is mostly a local copy that we can quickly restore if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Not in the GUI.  Microsoft's recommendation in KB323007 is to use the `/O /X /E /H /K` switches to xcopy in a command prompt, which will direct it to preserve things like attributes (including read-only), permissions, empty directories, and audit settings.